# react-virtualized CellMeasurer performance

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I plan to implement react-virtualized to my project as current solution is not able to deal with dynamic heights.

In my case, the list has different heights of items (height depends on content). Also, those items can expand and subtract on demand. Is react-virtualized can handle this sort of functionality with smooth animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well for us. We are using MultiGrid (so that we can have row and column headers) and we also have variable row heights. This requires using CellMeasurer. One thing to note, however, is that when using variable row heights, performance does suffer when you have a lot of columns. Even though the cells are virtualized, they still have to "render" (measure) every cell in the row in order to determine the row height for that row. I have found in this configuration that 50 columns is about the upper limit for reasonable performance. For fixed-height rows, this is not an issue at all. We are considering maybe using an algorithm that defines row heights based on knowledge of our data to avoid using a CellMeasurer for these cases where we have > 50 columns. This means we'll use a rowHeight function instead.
Brian has a link in the docs that discusses the performance isues of using CellMeasurer:
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md#limitations-and-performance-considerations

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.